# Converting varchar to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, casting

I am using SQL Server

I have a table that has date field set at varchar and it has the date there in different format

Example

```
OldDateOfBith
23/05/1990
4/6/1985
2001-01-06
```

I need to convert this field into a new field of type datetime

```
NewDateOfBith
1990-05-23
1985-06-04
2001-01-06
```

I can convert using

```
Cast(OldDateofBirth as datetime) -- will give error for 23/05/1990
CONVERT(DateTime, OldDateofBirth, 103) -- will give error for 2001-01-06
```

is there a way to convert all dates regardless of the format?

Comment: Is `4/6/1985` 4th June or 6th April? No one knows.

Comment: Its 4th June, 1985-06-04

Comment: Depending on the version of SQL Server, you might have the `TRY_CONVERT` function which will return `NULL` instead of failing

Comment: I still need the value, null is not good

Comment: Just take a second to think about it. `NULL` is better than having an error message that stops your processing. You repeatedly use `TRY_CONVERT` to get a valid date. If it returns NULL, you try the next iteration. Before you post again, first establish whether you have the `TRY_CONVERT` function. Also I am not convinced that a numeric date format will always be in YMD order. What makes you think 4/6/1985 is not 6th April? Can you see that it's an ambiguous format?

Comment: definitely error that stops the process is better than convert the date value to null. we dont use MM/dd/yyyy format in Australia

Comment: No. You include a WHERE filter that ensures it never applies NULL. It’s not going to write a NULL. A null tells you it didn’t work and you should try something else. This is better than the script failing with an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TRY_CAST()` and `TRY_CONVERT` functions. It's the best and easiest way to resolve your issue:

```
coalesce(TRY_CAST(OldDateofBirth as datetime),TRY_CONVERT(DateTime, OldDateofBirth, 103));
```

For fast check you can execute:

```
select coalesce(TRY_CAST('2001-01-06' as datetime), TRY_CONVERT(DateTime, '2001-01-06', 103));
```

Documentation links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know the exact date format of the string date it is impossible to convert

As a example '12/12/2018' In here you don't know which is day and which is month

Answer (score 1):

Find below an idea **only** for the formats posted on the question:

**--- Query Data ---**

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (OldDateOfBith) VALUES
('23/05/1990'),
('4/6/1985'),
('2001-01-06')
```

**--- Query ---**

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN OldDateOfBith LIKE '____-__-__' THEN CONVERT(DATETIME2, OldDateOfBith, 120)
        ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME2, OldDateOfBith, 103)
    END AS NewDateOfBith
FROM
    dbo.Test
```

The query above was tested on the following version of SQL Server **only**:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB4019088) - 13.0.1742.0 (X64)   Jul  5 2017 23:41:17   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 6.3 <X64> (Build 17134: )
```

---

Having that said, you may need to run this in multiple steps.

Comment: Unfortunately this can still fail depending on the query plan. If the query plan decides to run the where afterwards it will fail.

Comment: Oh, cool. Which type of failure and under which circumstances? Of course, in my test (single OldDateOfBith VARCHAR column), the query optimizer created a plan with 100% estimated cost on a Table Scan operation. Actually, that was my concern since depending on the database design, size, activity (e.g. TPS) and how the update is executed, it could lead to major side effects.

Comment: Sorry now that I re read it, there is no `WHERE` on it so it won't fail under those circumstances after all. It will only fail for example, for a value of ABCD/EF/GH or 2018/28/01. I know that neither of these cases are in the OP's sample data. For the given sample data your answer is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
SELECT TRY_CAST ( OldDateofBirth AS datetime) as newbirddate from...
```